# как изменить внешний вид возвращаемого JSON в РестКонтроллере?

Tags: java, spring

Возвращает :

```
{
  "filename": "filename", 
  "url": "uploads/year/month/day/filename"
}
```

---

Нужно

```
{
  "filename": "filename", 
  "url": "полный адрес файла (uploads/year/month/day/filename)"
}
```

Comment: А чем полный адрес файла в скобках ниже отличается от варианта выше?

Comment: ни как не отличается

Comment: Если ничем не отличается, то в чём тогда состоит вопрос? =/

Comment: надо дополнить ответ. Можно как-то это сделать?

Comment: полный адрес файла - эту фразу добавить

Comment: А чем ответ дополнять нужно? (UPD: а, понял)

Comment: Всем Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Отлично, в таком случае рекомендую прописать, что именно Вы сделали, чтобы изменить вид возвращаемого JSON, в качестве ответа, а его затем отметить как верный через нажатие на галочку слева :)